# Dependency injection for generic class

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have a generic class and a generic interface like this:

```
public interface IDataService<T> where T: class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

public class DataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Seed<T>.Initialize();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Initialize()
{
    List<T> allCalls = new List<T>();
    ....
    return allCalls;
}
```

Now in my StartUp.cs I'm hooking up the class and interface

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataService<>), typeof(DataService<>));
    ...
}
```

When I try to use it in my e.g. Repository.cs its always null.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDataService<T> _dataService;

    public Repository(IDataService<T> dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT
Here is the requested Repository Interface and class

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    double GetCallPrice(T callEntity, Enum billingType);
    double GetCallPriceFromIdAndBillingType(int id, Enum billingType);
}
```

And the Repository.cs class

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDataService<T> _dataService;
    private IEnumerable<T> _allCalls;

    public Repository(IDataService<T> dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }

    public double GetCallPrice(int id)
    {
        _allCalls = _dataService.GetAllCalls();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong that you are not showing in your question. Besides, to my knowledge, the built-in ASP.NET Core DI container does not allow injecting `null` values into constructors. Please show how you are registering and resolving `Repository<T>`, or more precise: please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 31):

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataService<>), typeof(DataService<>));
```

Ideally this should not be allowed, but as method accepts type as parameter, it took it without performing any validation. As nobody expected anyone would try to use it.

The reason it is null, because `typeof(IDataService<>) !== typeof(IDataService<SomeClass>)`

You can check example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/8g9Bx7

That is the reason, DI resolver will never know how to resolve. Most DI containers resolve types only if type implements requested interface or has base class as requested class.

Any DI container will resolve type A for type B, only if A inherits B or A implements B.

In your case, `DataService<>` implements `IDataService<>`, but `DataService<T>` does not implement `IDataService<>`

Only way you can make it work is by calling same for every data type

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataService<Customer>), typeof(DataService<Customer>));

services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataService<Order>), typeof(DataService<Order>));

services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataService<Message>), typeof(DataService<Message>));
```

**OR**

You can create a ServiceFactory...

```
interface IDataServiceFactory{
     DataService<T> Get<T>();
}

class DataServiceFactory : IDataServiceFactory{
     public DataService<T> Get<T>(){
          //.. your own logic of creating DataService

          return new DataService<T>();
     }
}
```

And register

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataServiceFactory), typeof(DataServiceFactory));
```

Comment: thank for your answer, however I'm not sure how to use it. What exactly should I do to make it work?

Comment: I'm not able to get your first solution to work, the second I just don't get

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft's Logging extension uses open generics in their [service collection configuration](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L42)

```cs
 services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

That line lets the closed version of the logger class be injected as

```cs
public SomeService(ILogger<SomeService> logger)
{
    // ...
```

Testing shows that, for a shared service scope, each different type of `T` will map to a different instance of the service, and that any valid type `T` that can be requested

If you want to play around with this, use this testbed: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dVDqnj

This approach assumes that behavior is not defined for specific implementations of the interface, but is more informational. If you need different implementations for `IGeneric<Foo>` and `IGeneric<Bar>`, you'll need to define each implementing service individually.

Comment: requires using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions; in Startup

Comment: Is there any way to template the ILogger parameter type?  i.e.  SomeService(ILogger<this.getType()> logger).  I want to prevent the situation at compile time where someone copy pasted and ended up with "SomeService(ILogger<SomeOtherService> logger) by mistake.

Comment: @PeterDrier, Not really. Generics don't support looking up to the referencing class like that, and even if they did, it would be the responsibility of the declaring code to set the generic constraint. You could write a static analysis check for this, but I think the solution here is to carefully review injected dependencies, which should really be happening anyway.